# Insert delayed and prevention of sql injection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, insert, sql-injection

Previously I used

```
Model.create()
```

to insert a row, now, I want to use DELAYED option in Mysql.

But, if I write

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT DELAYED INTO `TABLE` (`row`)  VALUES (#{params[:id]})")
```

so I get sql injection. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `connection.quote`

```
id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(params[:id])
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT DELAYED INTO `TABLE` (`row`)  VALUES (#{id})")
```